# How not to create new lines with php script

Tags: php

With the script below, I create links from a text file you, but when I create files, I can line added at the beginning and one at the end of lines, no way to prevent that from happening?
The first line of file.txt and Live1
and the last line of https://www.example.com/example/playlist.m3u8 but when I do the transformation in link.txt file, the first and last lines are empty, I would avoid creating empty rows, It's possible? where am I wrong?

This is file.txt

```
Live1 
https://www.example.com/example/playlist.m3u8
Live2 
https://www.example.com/example/playlist.m3u8
Live3 
https://www.example.com/example/playlist.m3u8
Live4 
https://www.example.com/example/playlist.m3u8
Live5 
https://www.example.com/example/playlist.m3u8
```

This is the script php

```
<?php
$file = "file.txt";
$fr = fopen($file, 'r');
$i = $x = 0;
$links = array();
while (!feof($fr)) {
    $riga = trim(fgets($fr));
    if (!empty($riga)) {
        if ($i % 2 == 0) {
            $links[$x]['name'] = $riga;
        } else {
            $links[$x]['link'] = $riga;
            $x++;
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
fclose($fr);

$output = "";
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $output .= "<a href='" . $link['link'] . "' target='blank'>" . $link['name'] . "\n " ;
$file = "link.txt";
$codice = "
{$output}
";
$fo = fopen($file, "w");
chmod($file, 0755);
fwrite($fo, $codice);
fclose($fo);
}
```

This is the result link.txt

```
<a href='https://www.example.com/example/playlist.m3u8'>Live1
<a href='https://www.example.com/example/playlist.m3u8'>Live2
<a href='https://www.example.com/example/playlist.m3u8'>Live3
<a href='https://www.example.com/example/playlist.m3u8'>Live4
<a href='https://www.example.com/example/playlist.m3u8'>Live5
```

Comment: Just so you know, you forgot to to close any of the anchors. You need `</a>`. But you're putting newlines in your `$codice = "
{$output}
";` variable, which is what's you're seeing. You could also look into `trim()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're *explicitly* creating new lines:

```
$codice = "
{$output}
";
```

If you don't want them, get rid of them:

```
$codice = "{$output}";
```

(Or just use the `$output` variable directly, since `$codice` isn't actually doing anything.)

Comment: The first line is gone but there is still a blank line at the end of file. Anyway Thanks